# Unity to Android scaling

Tags: android, scale, unityscript, unity-game-engine

Hello in my unity project i have made 2 levels but when i build and run them on android they always scale upwards or downwards either the buttons were way too big or the main menu icon was really small.. i was wondering if there is any way change the scale or configure the look from the editor. Any help is appreciated.Here are some screenshots. http://kharief.imgur.com/all/  ( i want the paper to be the background and scale down the buttons)

Comment: the image is private. Can't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the way the Canvas scales in the inspector.  You can either have the pixels set to a constant size, scale with the screen size, or maintain a constant physical size.